# Changing style sheet on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I want change the theme of my webpage, I need to do it for an asp.net page. what is the best way to change the looks of a web page. Just like that of changing the theme.
Please suggest the method and explain it

Comment: i hope this link helps you: http://4umi.com/web/css/changesheet.php

Comment: you can use php or javascript

Comment: @ChetanaKestikar Thats the simplest way, i worked it out in a different way. Thank you .

Answer (score 2):

Asp.net Skins is a great way to change the layout and style of a site..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use multiple ASP.NET themes that contain specific implementations of css/skins. In order to change the theme property of your page you may do so in Page_PreInit event. Just assign the Page.Theme property at runtime with the required theme name.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="mycss" />

$(document).ready(function() 
{
   $('#mycss[rel=stylesheet]').attr('href', 'style2.css');
});
```